# zend-mail fails due to connected party did not properly respond

Tags: php, email, networking, router, zend-mail

I used php  zend-mail to send emails. The codes worked fine before I moved to a new network environment. the php zend-mail codes I used are:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail->addTo($toemail, "{".$toname ."}");
$mail->setSubject($subject) ; 
$mail->setFrom($reply_email, 'staff');
$mail->setBodyHTML($msg, 'UTF-8');
try {
    $mail->send();
} catch (Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception  $e){
    $mailerr = $e->getMessage() ;
    echo  "Send mail fails : ". $mailerr . "<br>" ; 
}
```

I cannot send emails in the new network environment due to the following error message: 
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

I then opened a window 7 shell command window and tried to ping my mail server  pop.AAA***.com, I got "Request timed out" error message. I then ping other big domain names; but strange things happen. Some big domain names worked fine with ping but some do not. For example :

```
C:\Users\Jordan>ping www.hotmail.com

Pinging dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com [65.55.129.171] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 65.55.129.171: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=246
Reply from 65.55.129.171: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=246
Reply from 65.55.129.171: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=246
Reply from 65.55.129.171: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=246

Ping statistics for 65.55.129.171:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 18ms, Maximum = 27ms, Average = 22ms


C:\Users\Jordan>
C:\Users\Jordan>ping www.msn.com

Pinging us.co1.cb3.glbdns2.microsoft.com [131.253.13.140] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 131.253.13.140:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Here we see that I could ping www.hotmail.com, but I could not ping www.msn.com nor my email server pop domain. However I can access both www.hotmail.com, and www.msn.com in browser.

Could some expert tell me what was wrong with my zend-mail or networking setting ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some popular sites such as amazon.com, microsoft.com, slashdot.org, and other sites that have had DoS attacks in the past may disable ICMP on their servers or setup other network settings that prevent a ping request be received or responded to. Because of this when pinging these domain names or their associated IP addresses you'll receive a "Request timed out." or get a "100% packet loss."

This is normal behavior for these sites and there is nothing that can be done to get around it.